# If the ability to add application support Android ART?

Tags: android, art-runtime

After filling the application in Google Play for beta testing began to notice that people with Android 4.4 and a virtual machine ART application simply can not run. Is it possible to somehow add support for this virtual machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ART virtual machine should simply run your app without errors; you don't specifically need to "add" support for it. If it has bugs that prevent your app from working (or your app has bugs that are only exposed by ART), then you'll need to get an Android 4.4 device and test it out. There are instructions here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56773/dalvik-vm-vs-art-android-runtime-for-endusers on how to enable it.

ART is in experimental preview exactly so that developers can try it out and make sure there are no issues preventing their app from working before it's enabled by default for all users in a future Android release.

If you suspect it's an ART bug that's keeping your app from working, file a bug at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry and provide complete details on how to reproduce. It would be most helpful if you could narrow down the problem to what ART's specifically doing wrong instead of just filing a bug that says "my app doesn't work".

Comment: I took the Nexus 5 and Nexus 7 first and second generation. On dalvik everything worked well, but when you go to ART not even to install it

Comment: Probably the thing to do is treat it as any other debugging problem -- I'm not sure why it wouldn't install (isn't your app already installed?), but look at the messages in logcat, if the app crashes, debug it in the normal way. Don't immediately assume that it's an ART bug -- it's possible it's your bug, but it's just now being exposed because things run differently under ART.